# How to automatically create a separate Heroku Postgres for each Review App?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, continuous-integration

I have a Heroku pipeline with a separate app for the staging environment (`develop` branch) and a separate app for the production environment. Each of the environment apps has its own database enabled through Heroku Postgres (`DATABASE_URL` is unique for the environment). I also have enabled Review Apps – temporary apps for pull requests, which allows me to review the changes "in action" before merging them to `develop`.

[image: pipeline outline]

However, these temporary apps do not have any database attached to them. I want to have **separate independent instances of Heroku Postgres created for each temporary app automatically**; ideally, on subsequent redeployments, it would also be cleaned up or destroyed and created again from scratch. Is this possible?

Also, do I [need `app.json`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#environments-in-app-json) to do this? I'm not strictly against having it, but the whole setup so far has been made through Heroku UI, which is fun to use, and I would prefer to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an app.json file to make Review Apps working properly, including provisioning add-ons with the specific plan to use. Refer to the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#configuration) for additional configuration details.

EDIT: app.json may contain different options, but in your specific case this should suffice

```
{
  "environments": {
    "review": {
      "addons": ["heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe give a concrete example of `app.json` for my use case?

Comment: Edited the answer with an example of app.json